# Getting Wake on Internet (WAN WOL - Magic Packet) run on Windows 10? (Intel I217-V)

Tags: port-forwarding, wake-on-lan, wan

Under Network Adapters I have an Intel Ethernet Connection I217-V. With Windows 7 I was able to configure my computer to wake up on a magic packet, I am using the app [WolON](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitklog.wolon&hl=en).

After a fresh installation of Windows 10 it does not work anymore. The wake-on-lan however still works (i. e. I can wake up the computer when I am in the LAN).

I have installed the [64bit Intel Driver for the I217 family](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25016/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-Windows-10?product=70831). Only then the options for Magic Packet showed up:

[image: Magic packet settings]

Now I have no clue why it does not work anymore. I guess it is a driver vs. Windows 10 issue.

Has anyone solved this issue? Or do you have any idea how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

---

More information:

IP Forwarding Rules:

[image: IP Forwarding Rules]

There was a little issue (I have selected the new PC name and it shows up fine, but it is still not waking up, LAN however still works):

[image: fixed]

Settings of Port-Mapping:

[image: Settings of Port-Mapping]

By the way, the IP stored in the app matches the IP from my PC. These are the WolON app settings:

[image: wolon app]

Comment: Your machine should not be able to detect whether the packet orginates from the local machine or from the internet - the magic packet looks the same either way.  It is more likely (however coincidental) that your router configuration needs to be checked to make sure it is correctly forwarding the incoming WOL.

Comment: But it sound confusing, because with the old Windows 7 it worked. And just with Windows 10 it does not anymore. I haven't touched the router, since it was working beforehand.

Comment: Can you provide details of hoe the router is configured?

Comment: Wake-on-lan is a broadcast process.  Your router shows that you are sending the packet to a specific address - the address of the PC you want to turn on.  However, as that machine is off, the router will arp for the address, the machine won't respond, and so the packet will be discarded.  The destination should be the broadcast address - ideally going to mac ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff or it may work if you send it to the IP broadcast address for your network.

Comment: Please can you make sure you [edit] your question when providing more detail -  particularly the images, so they can just be viewed, and others don't need to hunt through the comments for the complete picture.